# Method for secure user sessions/encrypted access to user specific files/folders?

Tags: php, mysql, database, security

I am a non-developer trying to find a script or plugin that will allow me to create encrypted user sessions. A client would securely login to my site and based on username, each would be redirected to a specific page on the server or be given access to a designated folder containing their account info and documents.

I've seen a few scripts out there available at repositories that offer similar features, but I'm having a hard time determining what method best suits my needs as listed above. Any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not what you're probably expecting, but you are describing something that resembles to an FTP server, search for vsftpd. Have you considered that?

Comment: FTP traffic is unencrypted (much like sending an email), so if you decide to use this method, make sure you encrypt the file before sending or use a secure ftp client/server

Comment: Well, what I am intending specifically is to direct each user to a static page with an embedded video and a summary of their account and proofs of graphic design work that they can view and approve. I want the login to occur through the front page of my site, and upon logout, the user will be redirected back to the front page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a couple of answers, so I'll attempt here to answer my own question:

1) CodeIgniter may have some plugins that do what I am looking for.
2) aMember Pro does exactly what I am looking for and more, but with a $180 price tag.